# Retrieving Calendar Event from EventStore returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, calendar

I've been frustrated with Objective C the last 2 days.
We're making a simple application to read, write and update events to the iOS Calendar (iOS 9 and later). We selected Objective C as the programming language.

At this moment we're able to read calendars and add new Calendar Events using [Event Store.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkitui/ekeventeditviewcontroller/1613981-eventstore?language=objc) but we're having a big issue retrieving Calendar Events with the next code:

```
EKEvent* event = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier: eventId];
```

It is always returning `nil` and we're not able to remove the event from calendar.

This is the code we are currently using to add a new event:

```
if([eventStore saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error]) {
    if (error) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        NSString* id = myEvent.eventIdentifier;

        return id;
    }
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

It returns the correct Event Identifier, no error is present and Event is visible in Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ask for permission like this:

```
- (void)askForPermissionUpdateEventStore
{
    /* This two variables you need to declare like a properties */
    __block BOOL isAuthorized = NO;
    EKEventStore *eventStore;

    /* From this is the code required to ask for permission */
    EKAuthorizationStatus authorizationStatus = [EKEventStore authorizationStatusForEntityType: EKEntityTypeEvent];

    switch (authorizationStatus) {
        case EKAuthorizationStatusDenied:
        case EKAuthorizationStatusRestricted: {
            isAuthorized = NO;
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access Denied"
                                                                message:@"This app doesn't have access to your events." delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
            break;
        }
        case EKAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            isAuthorized = YES;
            break;

        case EKAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined: {
            [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent
                                            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                    isAuthorized = granted;
                                                });
                                            }];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, after this you can write and read events from the iOS Calendar the process is the same with reminders only thing changes is the type of object **EKEntityTypeReminder** or if you prefer you can check this [EventKit Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64513/cookbook-making-calendar-reminder), I hope it helps you :)